# List of all queries of Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m, daxstudio

Is there a way to get the list of all SQL queries in the first step of all Power Query. Please note, I am NOT interested in the source paths (server/database) which can be accessed through Option/Sources settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerBI Desktop, go to File -> About -> Copy session diagnostics to clipboard.

This will copy all your queries where you can then parse out the required SQL.

[image]